# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]' js

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]' js when using splice

I am trying to get new array with the specific value removed

```
const sourceColumn = eventColumns.forEach((event) => {
    if (event._id === source.droppableId) {
      const copy = [...event.events];
      var removed = event.events.splice(source.index, 1);
      // console.log(event.events);
    }
  });
```

result

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'

Comment: Can you show the result of a `console.log(event)`?

Comment: If filtering is what you'd like to achieve, you may want to use `filter` istead of `forEach` it won't fix the error, but might make things easier for you.

Comment: {
    "_id": "638d09470ee02deef33ba0a4",
     "title": "To do",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "M3",
            "description": "M3 description",
             "_id": "638f4b79f1e3fc605162a3a0"
        },
        {
            "title": "M1 ",
            "description": "M1 Description",
          
            "_id": "638f4b79f1e3fc605162a3a2"
        },
        {
            "title": "New Event",
            "description": "New Event Description",
             "_id": "6390623a905989849c700b4e"
        },
       ],
   
 }

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't return anything, so assigning it to a variable makes no sense, and I cannot reproduce with your code.

Answer (score 0):

using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const eventColumns = [{ "_id": "638d09470ee02deef33ba0a4", "title": "To do", "events": [ { "title": "M3", "description": "M3 description", "_id": "638f4b79f1e3fc605162a3a0" }, { "title": "M1 ", "description": "M1 Description", "_id": "638f4b79f1e3fc605162a3a2" }, { "title": "New Event", "description": "New Event Description", "_id": "6390623a905989849c700b4e" }, ], }]
 
const sourceColumn = eventColumns.map(event => ({_id: event._id, title: event.title, events: event.events.filter((_, index) => index !== 1)}))

console.log(sourceColumn)
```

using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const eventColumns = [{ "_id": "638d09470ee02deef33ba0a4", "title": "To do", "events": [ { "title": "M3", "description": "M3 description", "_id": "638f4b79f1e3fc605162a3a0" }, { "title": "M1 ", "description": "M1 Description", "_id": "638f4b79f1e3fc605162a3a2" }, { "title": "New Event", "description": "New Event Description", "_id": "6390623a905989849c700b4e" }, ], } ]

let arr1 = [], arr2 = [];
const sourceColumn = eventColumns.forEach((event) => {
    //if (event._id === source.droppableId) {
      event.events.forEach((e, index) => {
        if (index !== 1) {
          arr2.push(e);
        }
      })
      arr1.push({_id: event._id, title: event.title, events: arr2})
    //}
});

console.log(arr1)
```